# Bootstrap table pagination for reading the data from data-data="nameOfTheOBject"

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table and binding the data using {data: jsonObject}. I want to show the pagination for the total no. of rows (100) and show only 10 records per page but the jsonObject is only consist of 10 rows, How can I show the pagination in this case?